# Multiple XML files using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

This is a sample XML using JAXB from a Class

```
<Nodes>
    <Node>
        ...
    </Node>
    <Node>
        ...
    </Node>
    ...
</Nodes>
```

I want to keep each of these Node in separate xml. So how to design the Bean in java?

Comment: You have to admit, the question is less than clear as it stands. If you want each of these Node elements to be in separate Xml documents, just split your Xml document, and JAXB has nothing to do with it. So your question would be more about how you read individual Node elements into separate Jaxb beans ?

Answer (score 1):

I would create an XSD document that captures all your requirements and then have JAXB create the beans for you.

A good example on how to this can be found at:

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xml-schema-to-java-xsd-choice.html